# How to store users input in a list in tkinter?

Tags: python, list, tkinter

In my program I want the user to insert the amount of sold adult, senior, and child tickets for every cinema in a database. Since I don't want the code to be too repetitive I thought making a for loop or likewise would be the best alternative.

I need access to every element later and therefore I want to store them in a list. However, when I try to store the users input in a list and then print it, it's either blank or filled with just the most recent input. How do I solve this?

def help():

```
vuxenlista = []
vuxen = StringVar()

pensionärlista = []
pensionär = StringVar()

barnlista = []
barn = StringVar()

Label(fönster4, text="Vuxenbiljett").pack()
sålda_vuxen = Entry(fönster4, textvariable=vuxen)
sålda_vuxen.pack()

Label(fönster4, text="Pensionärsbiljett").pack()
sålda_pensionär = Entry(fönster4, textvariable=pensionär)
sålda_pensionär.pack()

Label(fönster4, text="Barnbiljett").pack()
sålda_barn = Entry(fönster4, textvariable=barn)
sålda_barn.pack()

vuxenlista.append(sålda_vuxen.get())
pensionärlista.append(sålda_pensionär.get())
barnlista.append(sålda_barn.get())



Button(fönster4, text="fortsätt2", command=lambda: info()).pack()

'''if elements == BIOGRAFVAL[0]:
            Label(fönster4, text="Vuxenbiljett").pack()
            sålda_vuxen1 = Entry(fönster4, textvariable=vuxen)
            sålda_vuxen1.pack()

            Label(fönster4, text="Pensionärsbiljett").pack()
            sålda_pensionär1 = Entry(fönster4, textvariable=pensionär)
            sålda_pensionär1.pack()
        
            Label(fönster4, text="Barnbiljett").pack()
            sålda_barn1 = Entry(fönster4, textvariable=barn)
            sålda_barn1.pack()

              
        if elements == BIOGRAFVAL[1]:
            Label(fönster4, text="Vuxenbiljett").pack()
            sålda_vuxen2 = Entry(fönster4, textvariable=vuxen)
            sålda_vuxen2.pack()

            Label(fönster4, text="Pensionärsbiljett").pack()
            sålda_pensionär2 = Entry(fönster4, textvariable=pensionär)
            sålda_pensionär2.pack()
        
            Label(fönster4, text="Barnbiljett").pack()
            sålda_barn2 = Entry(fönster4, textvariable=barn)
            sålda_barn2.pack()
            
        if elements == BIOGRAFVAL[2]:
            Label(fönster4, text="Vuxenbiljett").pack()
            sålda_vuxen3 = Entry(fönster4, textvariable=vuxen)
            sålda_vuxen3.pack()

            Label(fönster4, text="Pensionärsbiljett").pack()
            sålda_pensionär3 = Entry(fönster4, textvariable=pensionär)
            sålda_pensionär3.pack()
        
            Label(fönster4, text="Barnbiljett").pack()
            sålda_barn3 = Entry(fönster4, textvariable=barn)
            sålda_barn3.pack()  '''
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre].

Comment: done! I can translate also if you want!

Comment: You should not clear the three lists (vuxenlista, pensionärlista, barnlista) in each iteration of for loop.

Comment: hmm how do I clear the lists? is it because they're empty?

Comment: @acw1668: What loop are you talking about? Ella: He said _not_ clear.

Comment: @martineau OP code is inside a for loop initially, but removed the for loop part after update.

Comment: @martineau I posted a link with how I want it to work

Comment: @martineau So basically if there is any way to store the users input in different variables depending on what cinema (BIOGRAFVAL[ i ]) it is?

Comment: @acw1668 ^^^ do you know?

Comment: Ella, please don't put images of code in you questions — put the code. A minimal reproducible example is code other can actually run and reproduce the problem.

Comment: @martineau, I tried but it said it was wrong... maybe if I put it in as a comment it will work!

Comment: No, comments aren't a good place for code. Please keep trying to put everything in your question.

Comment: @martineau can you see it now? sorry I'm new here, I'm not used to how things work yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should understand that the code till `mainloop()` just run once. So if you to add extras to the existing code, it has to be triggered through an event. It is not hard to do this. As you havent provided an example that can be run. Below is an example that takes in user input and appends to the list.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def run():
    lst1.append(e1.get()) 
    lst2.append(e2.get())

    print(lst1,lst2)
lst1 = [] #this is very important
lst2 = [] 
e1 = Entry(root)
e1.pack(padx=30,pady=10)

e2 = Entry(root)
e2.pack(padx=10,pady=10)

Button(root,text='Append all the text',command=run).pack(pady=10)

root.mainloop()
```

In this example the user input is directly appended to the list. **It is very important to** initialize the empty lists outside of all functions, otherwise it will rewrite the current list with the empty list each time the function is run. I think this is the mistake you were making in your code. Just declare the lists outside `help()`, like:

```
vuxenlista = []
pensionärlista = []
barnlista = []
def help():
    #same bunch of codes....
```

Comment: Thank you! There are still some problems that probably are due to complexity with for loops in tkinter. I will check with my teacher tomorrow and we'll try to solve it. I really do appreciate your answer though.